# Пропал jquery.min.js с админки wp

Tags: wordpress

в админку заходит, но пропал jquery.min.js из за этого некоторые модули отрабатывают некорректно, нигде запретов неувидел, functions.php в этом плане чист

Ставил в functions.php непомогает, как решить проблему?

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'true_include_in_admin', 25 );
 
function true_include_in_admin() {
 
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' );
 
}
```

причем все остальные скрипты подключены

Answer (score 0):

Для подключения jQuery в Wordpress не надо указывать URL, те в вашем случае:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_include_in_admin' );
function true_include_in_admin(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```